# Action / Keylisteners do not work properly

Tags: java, swing, awt, jbutton, actionlistener

I have two frames (One main and one popup). On the main frame key & mouse listeners are added. Both work just fine. On the pop up there are 50 buttons. I have one action listener for all of them. It works fine. I also have key & mouse listeners. Mouse works. Key is flaky.
The same keyListener class used in main frame is added to the pop-up frame too.
As soon as the pop up shows, key listener works, once mouse click happens (Action listener kicks in) keylistener stops working. Please help. The code attached is a simplified version

---

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class key {
    private static  class toolsAction implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent ae) {
            log("Command " + Integer.parseInt(ae.getActionCommand()));
        }
    }
    private static void log(String s) { System.out.println(s); }
    private static class keyboardHandler implements KeyListener {
        public void keyPressed( KeyEvent e) { log("KB Press called ");   }
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) { log("KB Release called "); }
        public void keyTyped   (KeyEvent e) { log("KB Typed called ");   }
    }
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        JFrame pFrame = new JFrame("Frame");
        pFrame.addKeyListener(new keyboardHandler());
        Container pane = pFrame.getContentPane();
        pane.setLayout(null);
        pane.setVisible(true);
        pFrame.setSize(650, 300);
        pFrame.setVisible(true);
        JButton[] buttons = new JButton[50];
        toolsAction action = new toolsAction();
        for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
            buttons[i] = new JButton("" + i);
            buttons[i].setActionCommand("" + i);
            buttons[i].addActionListener(action);
            pane.add(buttons[i]);
            buttons[i].setBounds(((i % 10) * 60), ((i / 10) * 40), 60, 40);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is the `PopUp` thingy, I can only see the `JFrame` in the code. Please Learn [Java Naming Conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-135099.html#367) and stick to them. Also do read about [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html), seems like you hooked on to the language too soon, without giving any heed to the basics :( You are setting the `JFrame` to the visible state too soon, before you had finished adding stuff to it. Please do learn the basics first correctly.

Comment: unrelated: don't do any manual sizing/locating of components, **ever** - that's the exclusive task of a suitable LayoutManager

Comment: related: _don't_ use KeyListeners, they are way too low-level. Typically, keybindings are the natural high-level alternative. Your description sounds like you need to take a step back and explain your requirements (vs. the problem with an assumed solution path)

Comment: "Popup" thingy is in my real application. The example pasted has a single frame with 50 buttons and all buttons hooked to the same action listener. The frame has KeyListener. The KeyListener does not print out any thing. If I comment out the addActionListener line, miraculously Keylistener works. That is the problem I need explanation for. I used manual sizing in this example as I wanted to keep the code small.

Answer (score 4):

An alternative approach uses [`Action`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html) and [key bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html). The example below binds 10 buttons to the number keys, also using the numbers as the `MNEMONIC_KEY` of each.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

/** @see http://stackoverflow.com/a/14182227/230513 */
public class Key {

    public static final int SIZE = 10;

    private static class ToolAction extends AbstractAction {

        public ToolAction(int i) {
            super(String.valueOf(i));
            putValue(MNEMONIC_KEY, KeyEvent.VK_0 + i);
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
            System.out.println(ae.getActionCommand());
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame f = new JFrame("Frame");
                f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                f.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, SIZE / 2));
                for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
                    final ToolAction toolAction = new ToolAction(i);
                    JButton b = new JButton(toolAction);
                    String name = b.getText();
                    b.getInputMap(JButton.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW).put(
                        KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_0 + i, 0), name);
                    b.getActionMap().put(name, toolAction);
                    f.add(b);
                }
                f.pack();
                f.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually this does not serve my purpose. The key stroke short cuts that can be used do not substitute the buttons. Buttons serve a different purpose and keystokes provide other services.

Comment: +1 this is more like the way to go than an alternate approach. Keybindings is for Swing KeyListenr AWT period.

Comment: @Manu: This is just an example of what's possible at a higher level than `KeyListener` / `KeyAdapter`. The more buttons you have, the more valuable the approach becomes.

Answer (score 2):

The `KeyListener` will only be executed if the component, to which the listener is added, has the (keyboard) focus. If you click on another component, that component will become the focus and the keyboard events will be sent to its `KeyListener`s.
Not sure if that is the problem without seeing the code of the popup, but it's the problem in the posted code...

**EDIT**
you can add an `AWTEventListener` to the `Toolkit` to intercept all events independently of the focused component:

```
private static class AWTListener implements AWTEventListener {
    @Override
    public void eventDispatched(AWTEvent event) {
        log("AWT: " + event);
    }
};

...

    Toolkit toolkit = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
    toolkit.addAWTEventListener(new AWTListener(), AWTEvent.KEY_EVENT_MASK);
```

Comment: Yeah, by adding `pFrame.requestFocusInWindow();` to the `toolsAction's actionPerformed()` method, and making `JFrame pFrame` an instance variable, `KeyListener` is working. +1 nice catch

Comment: can be done, though I doubt that such a hammer is needed here :-) Even if really all keyEvents are required, a less-hammerlike option like KeyEventDispatcher might be considered first.

Comment: @kleopatra agreed! Actually intercepting key events is kind of a hammer... better work with the 'higher' events.

Comment: Could you guys share your *fix*? I actually have a single window in my example and KeyEvents are not getting dispatched to it even though mouse events (removed from the attached example) and button pushes are dispatched (this I would presume guarantees that window does have focus). Thanks in advance

Comment: @Manu the mouse event is NOT dependent of focus ("keyboard focus") but on the position of the mouse pointer

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger thanks. Then can you explain why if I remove ActionListener to the button, the KeyListener *starts* working magically?

Comment: @Manu I can't reproduce that! Not with the code you posted: if I do not add the ActionListener toolsAction, the KeyListener still does NOT get called! But if I add the KeyListener to a button, it gets called as long as that button has the focus. Probably there is more code involved than the bit you posted. Anyway, a GUI component should only get a key event (from the keyboard) if it has the focus - per definition!

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem by adding MouseMotionListener and in the mouseMoved method calling pFrame.requestFocusInWindow() & *also* adding focus request in the button's actionPerformed method.
Even with just one button in a frame as long as the ActionListener is added to the button, KeyListener does not work.
This is kludgy at best, but works for me. I would still love to hear from the community why my original code does not work.